# jquery quicksearch element to search not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, quick-search

I'm using a jquery plugin called  [quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) for filtering a list of comments.

Here is a snippet from the markup:

```
<ol class="commentlist">


        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-9">

            <article id="comment-9" class="comment">


                <div class="comment-content">
                    <p><span class="ecf-field ecf-field-1">

                <strong class="ecf-question">I CHOOSE :</strong><span class="ecf-answer">HTML5</span>

                    </span></p>

                 <p>I agree with HTML 5</p>

                </div>

            </article><!-- #comment-## -->

        </li><!-- #comment-## -->
```

What I want is to search by this `<span class="ecf-answer">HTML5</span>` so, if the search query match `HTML5` to  display the `<li>`items  which correspond with the search query.

The problem is that if I search for `HTML5` is searching through the entire  `<li>`item and not just through the `<span class="ecf-answer">HTML5</span>`

My question is how can I make it to search  through this `<span class="ecf-answer">HTML5</span>` but still remove all the  `<li>`item which are not corresponding ?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/2QAdv/) to have a better understanding of  what I'm talking about.

Is this possible ?

Comment: hmmm. I'd probably look into the go() method and test against cache[i]. Add a unique class to the P that contains the subtext. Take the element that cache[i] represents... ala.. $('.omitP:contains(query)', cache[i]'), if you get back a length.. you have a match. if not.... splice that value out of the array and decrement the matches counter. along those lines.

Comment: Oh, I'm a little bit confused can you give me a short example to understand better what I have to do. Thanks and appreciate your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've provided via JSFiddle, i saw that the cache var, that was the one responsible for being compared on the query, was being passed as the whole `<li>` inner-structure.

By editing the line# 134:

`return e.strip_html(this.innerHTML);`

to

`return e.strip_html($(this).find(".ecf-answer").html());`

...you are then telling the application to compare only the .efc-answer part of each item.

Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2QAdv/1/

**However**, there's another solution which is to provide to the quicksearch constructor, the `selector` value, as follows:

```
$("#id_search").quicksearch("ol li article ", {
                                               noResults: '#noresults',
                                               loader: 'span.loading',
                                               selector: '.ecf-answer'
                                               });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2QAdv/2/

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Cheers :)